# Connecting a pyboard via USB gives "Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0)"

Tags: usb, usb-modem, tty, modem-manager

When I plug a micropython (Arduino-like microprocessor board) in via USB it works just fine as a USB file-system, however I cannot use it as a TTY.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4 64bit.

When I plug in the device I get this in syslog:

```
Jun 20 22:01:24 halob ModemManager[801]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Generic' and '1' ports
Jun 20 22:01:24 halob ModemManager[801]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyACM0', unhandled serial type'
Jun 20 22:01:24 halob ModemManager[801]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-2': Failed to find primary AT port
```

the lusb -v output looks like this:

```
Bus 003 Device 050: ID f055:9800  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xf055 
  idProduct          0x9800 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Micro Python
  iProduct                2 Pyboard Virtual Comm Port in FS Mode
  iSerial                 3 000000000011
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           98
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         1
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          2
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        1
        bSlaveInterface         2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a /etc/udev/rules.d/49-micropython.rules file with the following contents:

```
# f055:9800 - MicroPython board
ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9800", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9800", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9800", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9800", MODE:="0666"
```

and then I executed:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

and then unplugged and replugged the USB cable going to the micropython board.

That works for me under 14.04

Comment: Perfect! As soon as I implemented this it worked flawlessly.

Comment: the main thing that helped me was `ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"` this command tells the `ModemManager` to ignore this device

Comment: @SalimFadhley hey i'm facing the same problem when i put this rules and reload it it work fine but when i restart the machine i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/714021?Linux-MSP432P401R-How-to-connect-dev-ttyACM0-on-restart

You can also use the following command to disable the Ubuntu Modem Manager service:

`sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service`

This service has a 30-sec init process which makes the device on /dev/TTYACM0 fail because is not a modem.

This worked for me under Ubuntu 18.04 even after rebooting the machine.